# Emacs flymake-jslint show all errors

Tags: javascript, emacs, jslint, flymake

I want to use jslint in emacs, so I installed package `flymake-jslint` and `flymake-cursor`.
I have really simple javascript file:

```
/*global desc, task, jake, fail, complete */
"use strict";
task("example", function() {
    var x = 5
    console.log("asdf");
});
```

Flymake properly highlights `var x = 5` and I get `Unused 'x'.` in mini buffer. However, when I run `jslint` from command line, I get:

```
$ jslint jakefile.js

jakefile.js
 #1 Expected exactly one space between 'function' and '('.
    task("example", function() { // Line 3, Pos 25
 #2 Expected ';' and instead saw 'console'.
    var x = 5 // Line 4, Pos 14
 #3 Unused 'x'.
    var x = 5 // Line 4, Pos 9
```

Is there a way to configure `flymake-jslint` to show me those non syntax error, like "Expected space"?

Comment: [This](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlymakeJavaScript) suggests you can set options in a config file: *Customize flymake-jslint options. On Windows set flymake-jslint-command to: ~/.emacs.d/jslint.bat* Alternately, you should be able to add `/*jslint white:false */` (etc) to ensure toleration of messy whitespace is *off* on a file-by-file basis. But try the config route first.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer :)

There is config variable called `flymake-jslint-args`. When i run `describe-variable` it showed me something like this:

> flymake-jslint-args is a variable defined in `flymake-jslint.el'. Its
>   value is ("--white" "--undef" "--nomen" "--regexp" "--plusplus"
>   "--bitwise" "--newcap" "--sloppy" "--vars" "--eqeq")
>
> Documentation: Command-line args for jslint executable.

All those command line arguments are types of errors, that will be *ignored* while running jslint, so I've set this variable to `()`.

```
(setq flymake-jslint-args ())
```

and now I get all the errors, like I wanted.